# Page reload doesn't reset jQuery / CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm designing an HTML page which has one button. The user clicks the button and a simple jQuery script animates that div away, revealing lower page content. You can see it [here](http://allhandsonline.com).

I've noticed that it looks/works fine the first time, but if I refresh the page with the browser button, it doesn't fully reset. The initial container is only half on the page. If I enter the URL again and load the page, it resets as expected.
**NOTE: This only happens if you scroll down a bit after clicking the initial button... which seems weird.**

I had no idea that there was any difference between these two operations, but there clearly is. What is the difference and how can I fix this problem from happening?

Here's my jQuery code, in case it's relevant:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var faqs = $("#FAQ");
    $("#learnmore").click(
        function(){
            $("#home").animate({top:'-=1066px'},600);
            $("#more").animate({top:'-=1066px'}, 600, function() {$("#background").hide();} );
            $("body").css('overflow-y', 'scroll');

            //$("#home").slideUp();
            console.log("jquery loaded");
            }
        );

});
```

Comment: It works great in chromium, what browser is failing?

Comment: WTF... the title and the question is two opposite things?

Comment: @Thijs: It doesn't work in Chrome. Click the "learn more" button and scroll the page before you hit reload. You'll see.

Comment: when it's reset it is only off/up as many pixels as I've scrolled down. Are you using cookies for screen height?

I don't know what's causing it but you might be able to work around it by putting a scrollTop: '0px' in the document ready function so that it gets you to the top on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because browser trying to scroll to the same position, what was before page reload. To check it, try press button and don't scroll to bottom of page and then reload page.
Okey, the reason is clear.

Now we need solution. Try this:

```
#more {display:none}
```

in your css. And then use

```
$("#more").show().animate(...
```

in your `$("#learnmore").click()` function. I hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### It happens because it is cached by the browser.

If you styles are regularly modiefied, then as easy fix is to attach a unique id on the end of the reference, like

```
<link href="style.css?time=168768234928" ..../>
```

What it does, it makes the browser think it is a new request everytime it loads.

Comment: So when the page loads, do I need to generate a random string of numbers for the end of the css link? Something like this:

`<link href="style.css?time=<?php //generate random number... ?>" ..../>`

Comment: kinda like `style.css?time=<?php echo time(); ?>`